# How to set the language in Gnome3?

Tags: language, gnome3

I have set up Gnome3 on my FreeBSD 8.2 box. Everything is fine, but one small problem: I can't find a way to set a locale. In (System settings - Region and Language - Language) shown only "Unspecified [US-ASCII]". ~/.dmrc and ~/.cshrc settings has no effect. Localizaton files seems to be installed properly in /usr/local/share/locale.
So, what can I do to set the desired language (or, at least, UTF-8 encoding)? Thanx for any help

Comment: OK, I've exported `LANG` in every `~/.*rc` file, in global and user-level `login.conf` and some almost random places. I don't know which of them helped, but now I have the right locale